# MySql Query - Math across multiple tables with count

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have 2 tables, one has a list of 'products sold' the other is a list of 'product prices'.

```
**SALES**
product_1
product_1
product_1
product_2

**PRICES**
Product_1 | 10
product_2 | 20
```

I need to count each products and multiply that by its cost.

The query should give a result in the following format:

```
NAME_________|______TOTAL

PRODUCT1_____|______30
PRODUCT2_____|______20
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join both tables using their linking column (*specifically the foreign key*), use aggregate function `SUM` and grouped them by their name.

```
SELECT  a.name, SUM(b.price) as TotalPrice
FROM    sales a
        INNER JOIN prices b
            on a.name = b.name
GROUP BY a.name
```